# How can I add a .com to my logo?

Tags: logo

I have a logo which I am happy with however I would like my brand to include the .com.  The problem is when I do the .com in the style of the rest of the letters it doesn't look so good.  When I don't match the style, and just put the .com in plain text, it doesn't look so good either.

Any suggestions as to better ways to add the .com would be appreciated.  Willing to modify the logo if necessary.

Thanks!
[image: Logo without .com and with stylized.com]
[image: Logo with plain .com]

Comment: I know this is not your question, so I'll leave this as a comment, do with it as you please: What rubs me the wrong way in this logo is that all letters in this logo are balloons, but the O's are a different style of balloon. I would either use regular letters and only make the O's balloons, or style all letters in the same balloon style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be my approach (obviously this is rough!)...

**Unite the "r" and "y"**

In my opinion the r and y there at the end are also a problem. So firstly I would reduce the shoulder on the r so that it does not have to sit so high to clear the y. So then you can bring down the r, and bring inwards and upwards the y - thus unifying these two awkward characters a little better.

**Use the "pocket" for the ".com"**

Then you can utilise the neat "pocket" in front of the y's descender for the ".com"

I know that kinda breaks the left to right readability, but I think it conveys the message that the type-mark IS a URL.

**Comic Sans lecture (supplemental reading haha)**

And lastly of course - and please repeat after me - NEVER use comic sans - No, not even for a balloon shop! Here I used (boring) Helvetica rounded. Mostly because I don't have VAG rounded installed. But please. Arial before Comic Sans! ;)

[image]

Comment: I promise to not use comic sans.  This looks much better, thank you.

Comment: If I can be a nit-picky jerk for a second does it feel too mid-90's with the .com like that?  Maybe with the stylized lettering it was already too 90's before the .com anyway?

Comment: Well brightly coloured rounded lettering is always going to echo the golden memories of Web 2.0 ;) But not sure what else you can do with kids balloons than make them rounded and bright! :) If I helped feel free to accept the answer :)